# read audio file information php

Tags: php, class, audio

How do I read information as bitrate, length, etc. Different file formats, mp3, wmw etc etc. from a sound file.

I guess there is some library/class out there, perhaps I could try out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried google, but I can't find anything proper. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-an-audio-stitching-tool-in-php/5810215 For example.. but that only seem to be working with WAV files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getID3()](http://getid3.org/) is a PHP script that extracts useful information from MP3s & other multimedia file formats. Last updated Aug. O8

Sourceforge Directory http://sourceforge.net/projects/getid3/files/getID3%28%29%201.x/

Another good one at [PHP Audio Formats Manipulation](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.audio.php)

Edit : getID3 works amazingly well.

Test Shot

[image]

Comment: No dll file available? Haven't been updated for a while as well!

Comment: @John I've put up a download link. I suggest you use it.

Comment: doesn't work for remote files